# pyqt: add clicked event for a Qlabel

Tags: python, pyqt

I've created label: `self.labelOnlineHelp = QLabel('<a href="http://example.com">Online Help</a>')` and want to make it clickable. Ideally it should open firefox (but not a default browser) and also change mouse to pointer (in a nutshell: just to create an usual hyperlink). I see that there is no clicked event in qlabel. Is there any way how to perform this in a simple way?

Comment: You could use a `QTextBrowser` element and disable it. It supports hyperlinks and should look like a QLabel (maybe disable the frame, too). I don't know about opening a non-default browser, though.

Comment: QLabel does not have a clicked event but it has mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent. Maybe you can use them.

Comment: @okorkut could you give a simple example how can I use this event. Do I need signals/slots for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [`setOpenExternalLinks`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlabel.html#setOpenExternalLinks)

```
self.labelOnlineHellp.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```

If you want to do something different than the default behavior (ie. open link in the default browser), you can connect to the `linkActivated` signal instead (don't use `setOpenExternalLinks` to `True` if you're handling the opening of the link yourself).

```
self.labelOnlineHelp.linkActivated.connect(self.link_handler)

def link_handler(self, link):
    subprocess.call(['/path/to/firefox', link])
```

Comment: Note, if you're trying to link to a file I needed to add the URL scheme "file://" to the link in order for it to open using .setOpenExternalLinks(True) on MacOS

Answer (score 3):

You need to reimplement QLabel class and override the mousePressEvent or mouseReleaseEvent. Here is a simple example:

```
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.link = "http://www.example.com"

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # open the link on your browser
        webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab(self.link)
```